# Add decimal places to string in java using String.format()?

Tags: java, string

I have

```
String str = "$2,542";
```

I want to format this string to:

"`$2,542.00"`

Is it possible to achieve this with java String.format() method???

Comment: @ whoever marked it as duplicate: I am not asking how to format a number, I AM ASKING HOW TO FORMAT A STRING THAT HAS NUMBER.., first read the question properly.

Comment: But you ARE asking how to format a number. Numbers have "a format" only when they are depicted as a string.

Comment: Your amount : `double amt = 123.456;`, make instance of NumberFormat like this
`NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();` then format your number:
`String formatted = formatter.format(amt);`